# How to integrate my compiler with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, eclipse-rcp

I have a mini-compiler written using flex, bison, and C++.I want to use it in eclipse
like using java compiler, but I don't know anything how to do that, so I want some help and some advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

"[Create a commercial-quality Eclipse IDE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-ecl-commplgin1.html)" could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to have a full-up integration (error highlights, code assist, etc) you have a really big job ahead of you. Start by reading the JDT and C++ implementations.

If you want to edit in a plain editor and just trigger a build, the cheap solution is to make an ant build script that can do the job. However, any command-line can be run as an external builder.